# Gutenberg - default parameter in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress-gutenberg

When I try to access a value that has not been edited by the user I get an error as the parameter does not exist unless edited in the Gutenberg editor. I would like the parameter to be saved even if it's the default. Is that possible. As a workaround I declare the default value both in Javascript and in Php like below which is not ideal. Hope someone can help!

```php
$formLink = isset($block['attrs']['link']) ? $block['attrs']['link'] : 'Default value';
```